# Stacking all the rolled vectors of a given vector in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

Given a 1d vecotr x of size n, how can we construct an n-by-n matrix X consisting of all the rolled vectors of x in PyTorch?

For example

```
x = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4])
```

The expected output is

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4, 1],
        [3, 4, 1, 2],
        [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Is there any better way than this?

```
N = x.shape[0]
A = torch.zeros(N, N)
for i in range(N):
    A[i] = torch.roll(x, -i)
```

Comment: `torch.as_strided(x.repeat(2), (len(x),len(x)), (1,1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Michael Szczesny for the comment.
For my own reference and for potential benefit to future readers, given a 1d tensor

```
x = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4])
torch.as_strided(x.repeat(2), (len(x),len(x)), (1,1))

>> tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 3, 4, 1],
    [3, 4, 1, 2],
    [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```

gives the stack of all rolled variants of x.

Similarly, given a 2d tensor

```
x = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
torch.as_strided(x.repeat(1,2), (x.shape[0],x.shape[1],x.shape[1]), (x.shape[1]*2,1,1))

>> tensor([[[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 1],
     [3, 1, 2]],

    [[4, 5, 6],
     [5, 6, 4],
     [6, 4, 5]]])
```

would do the trick.